# Getting a Token from Identity Server 3

Tags: identityserver3, identityserver4, identityserver2

I am trying to get a token from Identity Server 3 through a Post Call from an application residing on another server.

I am posting the following values to https://mydomainhost.net/connect/token:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array(
    'client_id' => 'myclientid',
    'client_secret' => 'myclientsecret',
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://myotherdomain.com/test.php',
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'
)));
```

But the following error is being returned:

```
string(31) "{"error":"unauthorized_client"}"
```

I have changed the 'client_id' value to a username which is for sure not configured and get the following:

```
string(26) "{"error":"invalid_client"}"
```

I only did the test with a username which does not exist to see if I get a different result.

Can someone let me know if this is an error from the application calling Identity Server, or if it's from configuration within Identity Server please?

Comment: Can you paste your client configuration?

Comment: I'm trying to connect to a 3rd party - not able to get the client configuration from them.

Comment: I agree with Boopathy's answer - you can double check clientid and clientsecret in client configuration.

Answer (score 0):

usually for this error message i check two things 
1. client secret against the client id 
2. whether the client is configured for authorization code flow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So it's probably from the configuration of IdentityServer not from API?

Comment: thats my guess.